# How to open an excel file in matlab, run a code, and then go to next file and repeat until all files are processed?

Tags: matlab

I have multiple data sets in separate excel files. I select my excel file with all the raw data, it reads the peaks in the data and stores them. There are hundreds of these excel files.

What I need is to store the peak data in a single excel file, but at the same time to label the top cell with the file number name, example 1810992, and then to vertically store the data in the column underneath. That in itself shouldn't be too hard.

But what I need is for the program to go to the next excel file in the folder that contains it and to repeat the process, but to put the next set of data in the next column.

I dont know how to open multiple excel files, or to open one and then gather the filtered data and store it in the next column and then go open the next excel file and repeat the process, like a for loop.

This is what the author of the code wrote, there is a UI that when you click open folder, this code runs.

```
[h.inputFileName,h.directory, ~]=uigetfile('*.*');

tic
file = [h.directory,'\',h.inputFileName]; %combines directory and file 
name
[~,sheets] = xlsfinfo(file);

tmp_dat=csvread(file) ; 
h.time=tmp_dat(:,1) ; 
h.rawData1=tmp_dat(:,7) ;
h.rawData2=tmp_dat(:,4) ;
```

Again this is for one excel file, I need it to then repeat the process but without me physically clicking. To go through the entire folder until all excel files have been read.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dir` command to list the files in your current directory.
You can also add a filter like the code below.

```
dir('*.xls*' )
```

It will list all the Excel files(xls and xlsx) of your current directory. Then you have to make a `for` loop to repeat the process.

In the program you have posted, you are using `csvread`, `xlsread` may be more appropriated.